# How do I call 3 Ajax once quickly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

I have script code like this :

```
<div class="row blue-chelsea" data-hospital="">
    <div class="col s12 m9 l10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
                <select id="selectHospital" class="browser-default auto-complete-element">
                    <option value="">Select hopsital</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
                <select id="selectSpecialist" class="browser-default auto-complete-element">
                    <option value="">Select specialist</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
                <input id="doctor_name" type="text" placeholder="Doctor name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" input-field col s12 m2 l2 center-align">
        <a id="btn-sch-doctor" class=" waves-effect waves-dark btn btn-orange">Search doctor</a>
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="schedule" class="collapsible z-depth-0 row no-border" data-collapsible="accordion" data-total="10" data-filter-hpt="" data-filter-spc=""></ul>
<div class="row">
    <div id="sch-doctor" class="col s12 center " data-page="1">

    </div>
</div>

<script src="/Content/assets/script/doctors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        doctors.getHospital({ el: $('#selectHospital') });

        var dropdownspecialist = $('#selectSpecialist');
        doctors.getSpecialist({
            hospital_id: $(this).val(),
            apiurl: '',
            spec: dropdownspecialist
        });

        $('#doctor_name').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var filHospital = $('#selectHospital').val();

                if (typeof filHospital === 'undefined') {
                    filHospital = $('.our-doc').data('hsp');
                }
                var filname = $('#doctor_name').val();
                if (filname === 'undefined') {
                    filname = $('#doctor_name_our').val();
                }
                var filSpc = $('#selectSpecialist').val();

                var load = '<div class="progress"><div class="indeterminate"></div></div>';
                $('#schedule').html('');
                $('#schedule').append(load);
                if (filname != null || filSpc != null) {
                    doctors.getDoctors({
                        hospital_id: filHospital, specialty_id: filSpc, doctor_name: filname, cur_page: 1, cur_size: 10
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        $('#selectHospital').change(function () {
            var dropdownspecialist = $('#selectSpecialist');
            doctors.getSpecialist({
                hospital_id: $(this).val(),
                apiurl: '',
                spec: dropdownspecialist
            });
        });

        $('#btn-sch-doctor').click(function () {
            $('#sch-doctor').data('page', 1);
            var filHospital = $('#selectHospital').val();
            var filname = $('#doctor_name').val();
            var filSpc = $('#selectSpecialist).val();

            var load = '<div class="progress"><div class="indeterminate"></div></div>';
            $('#schedule').html('');
            $('#schedule').append(load);
            if (filname != null || filSpc != null) {
                doctors.getDoctors
                    hospital_id: filHospital, specialty_id: filSpc, doctor_name: filname, cur_page: 0, cur_size: 10, menu: 'find_a_doctor_menu'
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

And the doctor.js, you can see here :

https://pastebin.com/k2hbPQtT

The code above has worked well. when click the search button, it will display a list of doctors. and when click the "show schedule" button, it will display the doctor's schedule

but here I want to change the flow, I want when I click the search button, it will display a list of doctors and all doctor's schedules immediately appear. so I want to eliminate the "show schedule" button.

my problem is how can i do that? and whether it will make the process slow?

I hope some people can provide answer options

Comment: Is there no one who can give the best answer?

Comment: Can you set up a working example, maybe with the rendered HTML or including the API URL? Also there are syntax errors in your JavaScript.

Comment: Of course it'll take more time to load than separate call (though it depends on quantity of data).